# Tomcat webapp failing to run on someone else's computer

Tags: postgresql, tomcat

I have an apache-tomcat (8.5.35) that runs a web app. It runs on different computers (Windows 10, Mac OS X) without a problem but won't work on a specific computer (also Windows 10). I am not really sure why and have spent hours trying to find out why it won't work. The log files display

> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferenceJdbc The web application [web-app] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it whenthe web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC has been forcibly unregistered.

Any idea why it won't work with this specific computer? I have postgresql 10 (x86) installed in this computer. I thought Kaspersky would have been an issue so I disabled it and uninstalled both the *Small Office Security* and *Secure Connection* but the problem seems to be linked into Windows or something.

I also tried different versions of tomcat, postgresql, and jdbc drivers (postgresql jar files).

Comment: "Won't work" is not very specific, it is unlikely that the error shown is the root cause. You have the source of that app ?

Comment: That message is just a warning and won't be the reason Tomcat isn't started (but it sounds as if you are using an old JDBC driver)

Comment: I think I've figured out the problem. The webapp failed to execute because there was a problem with the postgres database. The database structure did not have the right structure (e.g., table etc.).